# How to change the default site directory

Tags: php, wordpress, .htaccess, web

I just setup a Wordpress in my server (www.albertotry.esy.es) and I added via FTP a new site files, but if I try to access the site, I don't see the `index.html` of the new site but the default Wordpress site.

I'm pretty sure there is a problem with the `.htaccess` file:

```bash
# Do not remove this line or mod_rewrite rules and search engine friendly URLs will stop working
RewriteBase /

# BEGIN WordPress
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
</IfModule>

# END WordPress
```

What should I change to page that will display when I type "www.albertotry.esy.es"?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The `.htaccess` file you're using is the default WordPress one (except for that first line, which is a duplicate). It sends *everything* that is not a directory or file to `index.php`. If you want to load `index.html` when accessing the domain root only, then change the rule in question and add another after it:

Old Rule:

```bash
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

New Rule:

```bash
RewriteRule !^$ /index.php [L]
```

The `!^$` basically means "any string that is not empty" - in this case, the string is the request URI.

Then add a new rule below that one (you can also add it before, if you like - shouldn't make a difference):

```bash
RewriteRule ^$ /index.html [L]
```

Here, the `!` is removed, which changes the meaning to "any request URI that *is* empty. As a result, requesting `http://www.albertotry.esy.es/` will show the `index.html` file, but making any other request would rewrite to WordPress.

However, I believe that WordPress may check the content of the code between the comments `# BEGIN` and `# END`, so not sure if this is bulletproof. However, it does answer your question.